# Divs overlap when height is set manually

Tags: html, css

Here's the page: https://hamzicabdulah.github.io/Raptitude/

The divs with the "other-stories" and "footer" classes overlap when the height of the "other-stories" div is set manually:

```
.other-stories {
  height: 65%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .other-stories {
    height: 89%;
  }
}
```

If I remove the above code, the divs don't overlap. What's the workaround here, considering the manually set height of the "other-stories" div needs to stay there in order to work fine in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Set Float to footer and other stories.

```
.other-stories {
  height: 65%;
  float:left;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .other-stories {
    height: 89%;
    float:left;
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It overlaps, because the `<div>`s in your `<div class="other-stories">` are overflowing out of the div itself.

Why do you have a fixed height on `other-stories` what functionality are you trying to gain? Also, is there a particular reason you are using height %s?

Comment: I know they are overflowing because they all have their heights set to 50%, but I want to know if there is a way for them to not overlap no matter how many rows of divs there are.

Also, I have a fixed weight, because height percentage on child divs won't work in FIrefox unless height of parent div is also fixed. And yeah, I am using percents to get the elements to change their dimensions depending on the screen size.

Comment: There are multiple ways, it would depend on your desired outcome. My first guess would be if you remove the "height" attribute from the .other-stories class, you will achieve what you are aiming for?

Comment: If I remove the "height" attribute from the other-stories class, the page won't be displayed as intended in firefox. What are the other ways?

Comment: I would need to know what it is doing that you do not wish it to do in FireFox? If it is something patently obvious, I will have to get back to you in a little while, as I do not have FireFox on the pc I am on now.

Comment: The manually set heights won't work on the children divs unless the height of all of their parents is manually set too. That means setting the height on divs and images doesn't work in firefox when I remove the height from the other-stories div. It just keeps the default (lowest possible) height no matter what the height property is set to.

Comment: But that is a totally different issue. And no worries man, thanks for trying to help. I'll be looking forward to your reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

With flex is a little tricky. I suggest to change all, remove flex display and use bootstrap grid. Do you know?

Comment: I know, but my point was the achieve the intended functionality using CSS flexbox.

Comment: I was learning this functionality too so I'm not so expert yet in that. I'm learning at this site, I think it is a good guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/